# Coordinate transformation via diagonalisation of the metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, eigenvalue

Consider the following metric:

\begin{equation}
g_{\mu \nu}=\frac{1}{169}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
160 & -12 & -36 \\
-12 & 153 & -48 \\
-36 & -48 & 25
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

It has therefore the following line element:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{d}s^2=\frac{160}{169}\mathrm{d}x^2+\frac{153}{169}\mathrm{d}y^2+\frac{25}{169}\mathrm{d}z^2-\frac{24}{169}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y-\frac{72}{169}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}z-\frac{96}{169}\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z
\end{equation}

If I diagonalise the metric, I find:
$$
g_{\alpha\beta}=\left(\begin{array}{lll}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
Which means under a certain transformation I can write
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{d}s^2=\mathrm{d}u^2+\mathrm{d}v^2
\end{equation}
(Since one eigenvalue is $0$ it also means that there is a redundant dimension).

**Question**:

- How do I go from $(x,y,z)$ to $(u,v,w)$?
- What will be $\mathrm{d}u$ and $\mathrm{d}v$ in terms of $\mathrm{d}x,\mathrm{d}y,\mathrm{d}z$?

Comment: In your case you can use the Jordan transformation matrix J
$J^{-1}\,G_\mu\,J=G_\alpha~$ and $\vec{R}_x=J\,\vec{R_u}$

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I think Rs are for coordinate vectors. G is for the metric tensor. The indices are wrong.

Comment: I don't work with coordinate the indices are to distinguish between the metrices i.e $\vec{R}_x=\begin{bmatrix}
  x \\
  y \\
  z \\
\end{bmatrix}~G_\alpha=\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$